# Getting formated data from the result of using simplexlsx.class.php

Tags: php

I am using simplexlsx.class.php class to extract data from an Excel file which contains only two columns,
like

```
column-1        column-2
2017-06-06      25.98
2017-06-07      25.83
2017-06-08      10.265
```

but when I use the method $xlsx->rows() it is giving me result like this;

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2017-06-07 [1] => 9.75 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2017-06-07 [1] => 15 )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 2017-06-07 [1] => 18 )
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 2017-06-07 [1] => 14.75 )
    )
```

I want these two values(date and number) to be saved in two different variables, which further I will use to save them in database.

Kindly help me getting these two values in two separate variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You understand the array structure you are looking at?

Could break out with a loop like shown below.  Honestly the structure makes sense probably for what you need to do though as it is.

```
$rows = $xlsx->rows();
$colA = []; $colB = [];
foreach($rows as $i => $row) {
    $colA[$i] = isset($row[0) ? $row[0] : null;
    $colB[$i] = isset($row[1) ? $row[1] : null;

    //or in this loop access...
    echo "ColA: {$row[0]}, ColB: {$row[1]}";

}
```

**See the `array_column` answer for cleaner method.**

Comment: Jeez.  I honestly told myself that `array_column` wouldn't work with that.. doh.  Think I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

I think use `array_column` in [php doc explained](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) how can solve your problem

For example:

```
$first_col = array_column($records, 0);
$second_col = array_column($records, 1);
```

Check out the run time result [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c2da0c69bdcd42e9219cab06de927c1d125dbe5)

Comment: Dear, it is not solving my problem

Comment: @Farhan92 I updated answer with php run time online, you can click the link and check the result. I think it is what you want!

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciated, but this really solved my problem

`$dt1 = array();
$dt2 = array();
 foreach( $xlsx->rows()  as $row )
 {
  // print_r($row[0]);
  $dt1[] = $row[0].",";
  $dt2[] = $row[1].",";
 }

  print_r($dt1);
  echo "</br>";
  print_r($dt2);`

Comment: @Farhan92 but what I did is more simple than what you did. If you need to attach "," use array_map('your_function_to_attach_comma', $your_array);

Comment: hy @zt1983811 do you know how to add a third party library in codeigniter? 
much appreciated.

Comment: @Farhan92 you can use https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2012/05/07/composer-with-codeigniter/ but I think you better ask the question in another post so that I can answer it in more detail. Please accept the answer. Thanks